# Sharing stored procedures across multiple apps

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, architecture, data-access-layer

Team A has an enterprise app that uses ADO.NET for data access that executes stored procedures. The data access is encapsulated in it's own project (let's call it `DAL.dll`)

Team B is creating another unrelated app that's reusing the stored procedures in the enterprise app. This app is currently using the MS application block for data access. The issue we run into is that whenever Team A make any change to the input/output params in the stored procedures, there is a runtime error in Team B's app and this app needs to be updated to accommodate the additional params (or params that were removed). So, most of these go unnoticed until a user complains. At the very least, we would like to have the app throw a compilation error so that the build process warns us of the changes made.

One way to do this is to have Team B's project add a reference to the `DAL.dll`

I'd like to know if there are any other cleaner ways of solving the issue. We are ready to replace Team B's MS Data application block to use a different technology (Entity Framework?) if necessary.

Comment: "At the very least, we would like to have the app throw a compilation error so that the build process warns us of the changes made.", what more are you expecting from your build process than that?

Answer (score 3):

Among the other answers, I'd strongly suggest getting those stored procedures into source control, in a [Database Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx). You then may be able to use the features of your source control system to do several things:

1. Lock some of the code so that it *cannot* be changed
2. Give you notifications if the code *is* changed
3. Warn you if the stored procedures change in a way that would prevent them from being called
4. Branch the stored procedures so that each team can have their own version of changed code, while keeping the unchanged stored procedures common. You of course will need to separate the different versions in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other posters on this thread that you should not share stored procedure's across different .NET DLL's, that is just a recipe for disaster. I would also shy away from ORM's like Entity Framework if you are doing anything at all complicated with your database schema because ORM's excel at getting a simple object model translated from your .NET application classes into SQL tables and SP's, but traditionally do poorly at optimizing them for performance on the database side. There will be people who claim otherwise, and they may have a valid point if you are an expert in wrangling an ORM to do waht you want like they are, but chances are you are not and it will cause you headaches in the long run.

A shared data access layer might work, but conceptually you are then just changing the implementation of the dependency from some code that a DBA wrote to some code that a .NET programmer wrote. Yes, you can use integration tests to achieve better verifiability, but the same case could be made for SQL with tools like Red Gate's SQL Test. I would shy away from this approach if the two applications are already experiencing some sort of pain from sharing SP's. That is an indication that the dependency just should be done away with.

If it were up to me, I'd just make a new schema for Team B's app. You can read more about schemas in SQL Server here: [MSDN Schema description for 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You can think of them as namespaces for SQL Server but with some additional bells and whistles like permission and access control. Separating out your different applications into separate schemas on the same shared database will probably make for the most flexible implementation in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

> unrelated app that's reusing the stored procedures in the enterprise app

If these two application are really unrelated why are those sharing procedures or even the same database. I know this is a long read, but I recommend you to read this: [A Better Path to Enterprise Architectures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479371.aspx)

The partioning concept in there relates to the [bounded context in Domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Bounded_context):

> Multiple models are in play on any large project. Yet when code based on distinct models is combined, software becomes buggy, unreliable, and difficult to understand. Communication among team members becomes confusing. It is often unclear in what context a model should not be applied.
>
> Therefore: Explicitly define the context within which a model applies. Explicitly set boundaries in terms of team organization, usage within specific parts of the application, and physical manifestations such as code bases and database schemas. Keep the model strictly consistent within these bounds, but don’t be distracted or confused by issues outside.

It is expected you end with problems when you don't explicitely deal with this. You're lucky you're seeing early failures, as it can turn into problems much harder to find on the long run.

Analyze the problem again with the above in mind. Consider if you're missing some explicit context where this common functionality should live.

Answer (score 1):

My question is: which team owns the store procedured and the database shared? Usually as a good architecture/design, you should not have two different apps sharing same database / procedures.

A better way to share data/functionality between two different applications is through a services or API, so the team who owns the functionality would be responsible to maintain it.

Also, have a good communication between both teams is highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the owner of the DAL project, you could host web services and share the API. That way, you separate the Data Access Layer from the business logic, which allows anyone to use the same DAL without having to publish it to each different location.

From my point of view, it looks like both Team A and Team B should share the same core model and look at Multitier architecture as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it would make sense to create a shared DAL that both applications can share.

I would add unit tests (or really integration tests) to make sure the DAL is compatible with the apps after changes. That way your tests would fail if incompatible changes have been made

Comment: To expand even further upon this, I would suggest that you implement the Repository pattern, thus if someone changes the implementation in the DAL classes that are defined in the interface, then you will get a build error. There is, of course, the possibility of someone forgetting to put a DAL method signature in the interface and circumventing this non-implementation check, but the compiler would still catch mismatched arguments/parameters.

Answer (score 0):

"I'd like to know if there are any other cleaner ways of solving the issue."

The cleanest way is for Team B to sit down with Team A and encapsulate the relevant business logic into a shared API. It doesn't matter so much how you implement that API; what does matter is that the API's interface is documented and versioned so everyone knows what to expect.

One reasonable mechanism for this in a .NET environment is to use Microsoft's [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview).

In short, the question of "how do we share a stored procedure?" is most likely looking at the wrong level of abstraction.